# How can I use the setName function to set the name of a file from a cell in google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Let me start by saying im a complete novice to app script. I cobbled together the following script from a few different sources online in order to export a PDF of one tab in my google sheet. The last problem Im running into is I want to rename my PDF to the name of a cell on one of the tabs in my sheet (see function namePDF at the bottom). What I can't figure out is how to set the name of the PDF to something other than a static string (see the line newFile.setName(nameSheet).)

Currently, this sets the name of the PDF to:

"PDF

```
function nameSheet() {  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('STRT');  var name=sh.getCurrentCell().offset(3, 6).getValue();//2 rows down and 4 columns to the right}"
```

I have to be able to set the name dynamically because this sheet is a template and is copied a ton.

```
function exportSheet() {
var sheetName = "CB"

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
for (var i = 0; i \< sheets.length; i++) {
if (sheets\[i\].getSheetName() !== sheetName) {
sheets\[i\].hideSheet()
}
}
var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(ss.getBlob());
for (var i = 0; i \< sheets.length; i++) {
sheets\[i\].showSheet()
}
newFile.setName(nameSheet);
newFile.moveTo(DriveApp.getFolderById(""));
//I just did this to move the file to somewhere else.
}
function nameSheet() {
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sh=ss.getSheetByName('STRT');
var name=sh.getCurrentCell().offset(3, 6).getValue();//2 rows down and 4 columns to the    right
}
```

Comment: `DriveApp.getFileById("id").setName();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change line 15 to this:

```
newFile = newFile.setName(nameSheet());
```

and line 24 like this:

```
return name
```

This way, the nameSheet function can return a value
and the setName function can gather that value.

Comment: Thanks a ton, that halfway solved the problem. Im not getting any errors anymore, however the name of the PDF is now just the name of the spreadsheet, not the contents of the cell on the 'STRT' tab. Looks like the function sheetName just isn't doing anything to actually rename the PDF.

Comment: I have edited the answer to solve that issue. You need to rewrite newFile after setting the name, otherwise that change is lost.